# Solve $\sqrt{1+\sqrt{1-4x^2}}=x\left( 1+\sqrt{1+\sqrt{1+2\sqrt{1-4x^2}}}\right).$

Tags: algebra-precalculus

Solve the equation with radical : $\sqrt{1+\sqrt{1-4x^2}}=x\left( 1+\sqrt{1+\sqrt{1+2\sqrt{1-4x^2}}}\right).$
This is  homework of my brother.

Comment: When i find a solution for this problem i meet an system equations : $\begin{cases} 2=a(1+\sqrt{1+b})\\ 2a^2+b^2=3\end{cases}$.

Comment: This does not appear to have a simple closed form solution. Wolfram Alpha gives the answer as $0.464164...$.

Comment: Are you sure you didn't include one extra $\sqrt{1+...}$? If you remove one from the right-hand side, the solution will become a lot nicer :-)

Comment: Did someone try $2x = \sin\alpha$?

Comment: I try set $2x=\sin t$ but trigonometric equation is not eassy for me .

Comment: Perhaps set $u=\sqrt{1-4x^{2}}$, so $x = \sqrt{1-u^{2}}/2$ and the problem becomes $2=\sqrt{1-u}(1+\sqrt{1+\sqrt{1+2u}})$...?

Answer (score 2):

For what it's worth, the substitutions

$$x=\sqrt{1-u^2\over4}\quad\text{and}\quad u={v^2-1\over2}$$

lead to the polynomial

$$v^6-6v^4+16v^3+41v^2-48v-32=0$$

which has roots $v\approx-0.50147404431$ and $v\approx1.32042574197$.  The negative root is nonsensical here, but the positive root corresponds to the value $x\approx0.46416402362$ that's already been reported.  As near as I can tell, the degree-six polynomial does not factor over the integers; whether it can be solved in radicals I'll leave to the Galois theorists out there....

Answer (score 0):

There is no closed form solution to this as far as I can tell. We can however approximate it to find:
$x\approx0.464164$

I hope this helps.
Best wishes, $\mathcal H$akim.